# set_table_styles not displaying in VSCode

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, styling

Python 3.9.5

Pandas 1.2.4

I'm trying to learn about using Styling to my pandas and specifically applying borders.  However I can't seem to get my display to reflect correctly when using set_table_styles.  Even doing a direct copy of another website.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/display-the-pandas-dataframe-in-table-style-and-border-around-the-table-and-not-around-the-rows/

Using this code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[14, 4, 5, 4, 1], 
                "B":[5, 2, 54, 3, 2],  
                "C":[20, 20, 7, 3, 8], 
                "D":[14, 3, 6, 2, 6]})


# making a green border
df.style.set_table_styles([{'selector' : '','props' : [('border','2px solid green')]}])
```

Just gives me the standard panda output without any border.
`
when I use:

```
df.render()
```

there's no mention of the green border in there.  What do I need to be doing to have the styles saved?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: *Styling* only styles for HTML rendering. So it indeeds does what it is expected to do in a Jupyter notebook. But for almost any other use case (IDLE, PyCharm, terminal, etc.) it has not effect.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this:

```
# making a yellow border
html=df.style.set_table_styles(
    [{"selector": "", "props": [("border", "10px solid yellow")]}]
).render()
  
# write html to file
text_file = open("index.html", "w")
text_file.write(html)
text_file.close()
```

Then open the Html file.